# My google calendar api just doesn't do not return events list to other accounts

Tags: codeigniter, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm logged in browser with my Google account, and every single Google account I use in my web site works fine with the Google Calendar events list, but if I log out or logged with another account on browser Google Calendar get events list stop working giving me these errors:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

This is my actual code in .js (I'm working with codeigniter 3 hmvc)

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'inicio/getAccess',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            initGoogleAPI(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
function loadGoogleAPI() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', {
            callback: resolve,
            onerror: function (err) {
                console.error('Error al cargar la API de Google', err);
                // Manejar el error aquí
            },
            timeout: 10000,
            ontimeout: function () {
                console.error('Tiempo de espera al cargar la API de Google');
                // Manejar el tiempo de espera aquí
            }
        });
    });
}
function initGoogleAPI(response) {
    correo = response.correo;
    loadGoogleAPI().then(() => {
        gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: response.clientID, scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly' });
        loadClient(response.apiKey).then(execute);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al cargar la API de Google', error);
    });
}
function loadClient(apiKey) {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest")
        .then(function () { /*console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");*/ },
            function (err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}
function execute() {
    var now = new Date();
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        "calendarId": correo,
        "orderBy": "startTime",
        "showDeleted": false,
        "maxResults": 4,
        "showHiddenInvitations": false,
        "singleEvents": true,
        "timeMin": now.toISOString(),
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            descHTML = [];
            eventos = response.result.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < eventos.length; i++) {
                var fechaHora = new Date(eventos[i].start.dateTime);
                var hora = fechaHora.toLocaleTimeString('es-ES', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
                var dia = fechaHora.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', { weekday: 'long' }) + " " + fechaHora.toLocaleString('es-ES', { day: '2-digit' });
                var mes = fechaHora.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', { month: 'long' });
                $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #titulo").text(eventos[i].summary);
                $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #dia").text(dia.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dia.slice(1));
                $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #mes").text(mes.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mes.slice(1));
                $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #hora").text(hora);
                $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #irEvento").css("display", "block");
                $('#Ev' + (i + 1)).find("#irEvento").data('href', eventos[i].hangoutLink);
                //$("#Ev" + (i + 1)).attr("href", eventos[i].htmlLink);
                if (eventos[i].description) {
                    $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #tamaño").text(limpiarHTML(eventos[i].description));
                    descHTML.push(eventos[i].description);
                } else {
                    $("#Ev" + (i + 1) + " #tamaño").text("No hay descripción.");
                    descHTML.push("No hay descripción.");
                }
                const imagenFinal = `<div class="eventosHoyImg" style="width: 107%; color: white; opacity: 0.75;">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size: 2vw;"></i><br>
                                        <span>Más Info</span>
                                    </div>`;
                $('#Ev' + (i + 1) + ' .eventosProxImg').append(imagenFinal);
            }
            $('.cargandoSpinner').remove();
        },
        function (err) {
            console.error("Error al obtener eventos del calendario", err);
            /*setTimeout(function () {
                        execute();
            }, 1000);*/
        });
}
```

This is the controller function:

```
    {
        if (!$this->getUserValidation()) {
            redirect('');
        }
        $jsonString = file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'libraries/credentials.json');
        $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

        $clientID = $data['web']['client_id'];
        $usuario = new stdClass();
        if ($this->input->cookie('usuario')) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('usuario', unserialize($this->input->cookie('usuario')));
        }
        if ($session = $this->session->userdata('usuario')) {
            $usuario->correo = $session->CORREO;
        }
        $response = array("apiKey" => API_KEY, "clientID" => $clientID, "correo" => $usuario->correo);

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

I already tried to solve this, but everything I tried just doesn't work :(